# Как в программе 3D Blender сделать анимацию?

Tags: blender

Как в программе 3D Blender сделать анимацию? Представим на сцене есть модель маленького города, есть дома. Чтобы было обяснить проше приведу пример. Представьте вы взяли смартфон, вышли на улицу, включили камеру и идете по улицам пешком. Здесь происходит анимация только камеры. Я узнал что в блендере есть такой возможность "Навигация ходьбой" w перед s назад a лево d право. Думаю вы меня поняли.

Comment: Думаю, лучше этот вопрос задать на специализированном сайте по блендеру: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @VerNick этот сайт на английском языке

Comment: @VerNick а что мешает перевести любой вопрос отсюда и задать его на соответствующем английском ресурсе? Зачем тогда нужен этот сайт?

Comment: @Crantisz Все вопросы, заданные по Blender, связаны с программированием

Comment: @VerNick https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8018/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%81-blender

Answer (score 1):

Нужно включить запись ключевых кадров [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в окне таймлайна.

Затем нажать вспроизведение анимации [image: введите сюда описание изображения] или <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

И наконец перейти в режим навигации камерой <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (что вы уже описали)

Пока проигрываются анимация, любое движение камеры (и не только) записывается в ключевые кадры.

Comment: Спасибо помогло ваш ответ, это хотел узнать

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! В этом случае нужно отмечать вопрос как верный, а не писать комментарии. Ознакомьтесь с правилами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Я понял на ваш ответ. Теперь вы можете дать ссылки (источники) к конкретным обучающим материалам где идет речь именно по этой теме, это может быть учебники или видеоуроки. Имею в виду откуда вы знаете.

Comment: Кто знает как сделать функцию "Навигация ходьбой" более плавный?

Comment: Не задавайте новые вопросы в комментариях. Во-первых, это не по правилам сайта. Во -вторых, здесь нет форматирования и изображений, т.е. отвечать неудобно. А так, в настройках, вкладка Input. Выложил бы скриншот, но...