# Как заполнить внутри и разделить на сетку заполненное?

Tags: blender

Да так чтобы глазки, рот и нос были отдельно ..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ммм...а в чем проблема? Я не уверен, что данный вопрос подходит для stackoverflow. Вопросы здесь касаются программирования и администрирования. Как работать в Blender'e нужно спрашивать на других ресурсах.

Comment: @Михаил Ребров - А какой есть ресурс наподобие stackoverflow для blender ?

Comment: @Михаил Ребров - Однако с вами не соглошусь что тут чисто программирования и администрирования  есть и 3d моделирование https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901162/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-3d-blender-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e?rq=1

Comment: ресурс наподобие stackoverflow для blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: моё дело предупредить. Если вопрос останется и его не удалят - буду рад за Вас. Относительно тем: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)